# Is there a Better way to run a command or shell on Docker swarm

Tags: docker

Lets say I want to edit a config file for an NGINX Docker service that is replicated across 3 nodes.

Currently I list the services using `docker service ls`.

Then get the details to find a node running a container for that service using `docker serivce ps servicename`.

Then ssh to a node where one of the containers is running.

Finally, `docker exec -it containername bash`. Then I edit the config file.

Two questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this rather than ssh to a node running a container?  Maybe there is a swarm or service command to do so?
2. If I were to edit that config file on one container would that change be replicated to the other 2 containers in the swarm?

The purpose of this exercise would be to edit configuration without shutting down a service.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be exec'ing into containers to change their configuration, and so docker has not created an easy way to do this within Swarm Mode. You could use classic swarm to avoid the need to ssh into the other host, but I still don't recommend this.

The correct way to do this is to migrate your configuration file into a `docker config` entry. Version your config name. Then when you want to update it, you create a new version with the desired changes, and do a rolling update of your service to use that new configuration.

Unless the config is mounted from an external source like NFS, changes to one config in one container will not apply to other containers running on other nodes. If that config is stored locally inside your container as part of it's internal copy-on-write filesystem, then no changes from one container will be visible in any other container.